# Querying & purging data between date and getdate()

Tags: t-sql

I've tried to search the question history for this similar issue but could not find anything that matched what I am trying to do. Hopefully someone can assist. I have a table that has some archive data in it that has a timestamp back to 1/1/1900. Not sure how that date came about, i think it may have been timestamped based on some older application. Anyway that data is good, valid data that my company needs to retain in those archive tables. However in an effort to clean out data periodically going forward, we want to be able to purge data that has a date older than 60 days but without touching the data with that old timestamp of year 1900. Is there a way i can use the between syntax to accomplish this? I was thinking i could do something like this but may be oversimplifying it:

--example:
--Query to find the records older than 60 days & dump into temp table

```
select transid into #cdm_delete_table from cdmtrans where exporttime < getdate()-60
```

--Then with those records saved in my temp table, perform my delete from the main table. 
--But this gets rid of ALL the records like you'd expect

```
delete from cdmtrans where transid in (select transid from #cdm_delete_table)
```

--However, i'm wanting to do a delete based on a range of dates. 
--Older then 60 days but greated than 01/01/1900. Would this work??

```
delete FROM cdmtrans WHERE transid BETWEEN '01/01/1901' and getdate()-60
```

OR

```
delete from cdmtrans where transid in 
(select transid from #cdm_delete_table WHERE transid BETWEEN '01/01/1901' and getdate()-60)
```

This is where i'm getting lost. Hoping someone could clarify for me if i'm on the right track. Thx in advance.

Comment: Yes, what you are thinking will work... If you are a bit uncomfortable, first run the query as a select to see what records will be deleted ....  `Select * from cdmtrans WHERE transid BETWEEN '01/01/1901' and getdate()-60 `

Comment: Btw: if you're happy with a particular answer, you can mark it as '[accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)' by ticking it!

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you what you need:

```
DELETE FROM cdmtrans
WHERE exporttime < getdate() -60
AND exporttime <> '1900-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track. I think you are looking for a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM cdmtrans
WHERE exporttime > '19010101'
AND exporttime < getdate() - 60;
```

(Note that you do not need the `transid` in your query to delete the correct records.)

If you want to check if this gives you the right set-to-delete, make a `SELECT` of the query first, as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM cdmtrans
WHERE exporttime > '19010101'
AND exporttime < getdate() - 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` comparator can be your friend. Use it to select records that don't equal `'01/01/1901'` and are older than 60 days.

```
-- select all records older than 60 days and are not '1/1/1900' into temp table
SELECT  transid
INTO    #cdm_delete_table
FROM    cdmtrans
WHERE   exporttime < DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), 60)
        AND exporttime != '01/01/1901'

-- remove from main table
DELETE
FROM    cdmtrans
WHERE   transid IN (
            SELECT  transid
            FROM    #cdm_delete_table
        )

-- or skip the temp table and do it in one query
DELETE
FROM    cdmtrans
WHERE   exporttime < DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), 60)
        AND exporttime != '01/01/1901'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I didn't think about using the AND as part of the equations. Makes sense.